# understanding primeFactorsR method with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following method that displays all prime multiples of a number in this case 20. I understand most of the recursive behavior of the method, but I'm kind of confuse after printing the number 5, why does n goes back to be 10 when it was 5 in the previous call(that is when executing the third recursive method)

```
public class Tester {     

    static boolean isPrime(int p)
    {
        for(int i = 2; i < p; i++)
        {
            if(p % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


   public static void primeFactors(int n)
   {
       primeFactorsR(n, n-1);
   }

   static int count1 = 1, count2 = 1, count3 = 1, count4 = 1;

   public static void primeFactorsR(int n, int m)
      {
         if(isPrime(n))
         {
             System.out.println(n);
             System.out.println("method1 " +count1++);
         }     
         else
            if(n % m == 0)
            {
               System.out.println("n " + n + " m " + m);
               System.out.println("method2: " + count2++);
               primeFactorsR(m, m-1);

               System.out.println("n " + n + " m " + m);
               System.out.println("method3: " + count3++);
               primeFactorsR(n/m, (n/m)-1);              
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("n " + n + " m " + m);
               //System.out.println("n " + n + " m - 1 " + ( m-1));
               System.out.println("method4: " + count4++);
               primeFactorsR(n, m-1);
            }
      }


    public static void main(String[] args) {  


           primeFactors(20);        

    }
}
```

output

```
n 20 m 19
method4: 1
n 20 m 18
method4: 2
n 20 m 17
method4: 3
n 20 m 16
method4: 4
n 20 m 15
method4: 5
n 20 m 14
method4: 6
n 20 m 13
method4: 7
n 20 m 12
method4: 8
n 20 m 11
method4: 9
n 20 m 10
method2: 1
n 10 m 9
method4: 10
n 10 m 8
method4: 11
n 10 m 7
method4: 12
n 10 m 6
method4: 13
n 10 m 5
method2: 2
5
method1 1
n 10 m 5
method3: 1
2
method1 2
n 20 m 10
method3: 2
2
method1 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in your second if statement `n % m == 0` it does two calls to `primeFactorsR`. The first call leads you deeper into the stack where it works out that 5 is prime. It then returns back up the stack until it reaches where it left off and moves on the the second print statement giving you the second n 10 m 5. Here is your output with it indented each layer and printing out how deep in the stack it is when it first enters `primeFactorsR` and when it finishes. Where it is heading right is going deeper into the stack and the layer above is paused. When the layer has finished processing it returns to the layer above, if that layer has more to do then it will continue from where it left off.

```
We are the top layer
n 20 m 19
method4: 1
   We are 1 layers deep
   n 20 m 18
   method4: 2
      We are 2 layers deep
      n 20 m 17
      method4: 3
         We are 3 layers deep
         n 20 m 16
         method4: 4
            We are 4 layers deep
            n 20 m 15
            method4: 5
               We are 5 layers deep
               n 20 m 14
               method4: 6
                  We are 6 layers deep
                  n 20 m 13
                  method4: 7
                     We are 7 layers deep
                     n 20 m 12
                     method4: 8
                        We are 8 layers deep
                        n 20 m 11
                        method4: 9
                           We are 9 layers deep
                           n 20 m 10
                           method2: 1
                              We are 10 layers deep
                              n 10 m 9
                              method4: 10
                                 We are 11 layers deep
                                 n 10 m 8
                                 method4: 11
                                    We are 12 layers deep
                                    n 10 m 7
                                    method4: 12
                                       We are 13 layers deep
                                       n 10 m 6
                                       method4: 13
                                          We are 14 layers deep
                                          n 10 m 5
                                          method2: 2
                                             We are 15 layers deep
                                             Prime 5
                                             method1 1
                                             Finished with layer 15
                                          n 10 m 5
                                          method3: 1
                                             We are 15 layers deep
                                             Prime 2
                                             method1 2
                                             Finished with layer 15
                                          Finished with layer 14
                                       Finished with layer 13
                                    Finished with layer 12
                                 Finished with layer 11
                              Finished with layer 10
                           n 20 m 10
                           method3: 2
                              We are 10 layers deep
                              Prime 2
                              method1 3
                              Finished with layer 10
                           Finished with layer 9
                        Finished with layer 8
                     Finished with layer 7
                  Finished with layer 6
               Finished with layer 5
            Finished with layer 4
         Finished with layer 3
      Finished with layer 2
   Finished with layer 1
Finished
```

Comment: when I debug->step into with netbeans it shows that method3 n=20 m=10 executes first and then method3 n=10 m=5 executes that is the last two methods, and your output shows the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I added more info to console output, to make recursive calls chain visible.
`recursionLevel` shows depth of recursion.
Each `primeFactorsR`-function call receives unique ID (see `funcId`-variable).
Sequence of function ids creates unique recursive calls path - `recursionPath`.

```
public class Tester {

    static boolean isPrime(int p) {
        for (int i = 2; i < p; i++) {
            if (p % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void primeFactors(int n, int recursionLevel) {
        primeFactorsR(n, n - 1, recursionLevel, null);
    }

    static int count1 = 1, count2 = 1, count3 = 1, count4 = 1;
    private static int recursionId = 1;

    public static void primeFactorsR(int n, int m, int recursionLevel, String recursionPath) {
        int funcId = recursionId++;

        if (recursionPath == null)
            recursionPath = String.format("%s", funcId);
        else
            recursionPath = String.format("%s-%s", recursionPath, funcId);

        if (isPrime(n)) {
            System.out.println(String.format("n %s recursionLevel %s recursionPath %s", n, recursionLevel, recursionPath));
            System.out.println("method1 " + count1++);
        } else if (n % m == 0) {
            System.out.println(String.format("n %s m %s recursionLevel %s recursionPath %s", n, m, recursionLevel, recursionPath));
            System.out.println("method2: " + count2++);
            primeFactorsR(m, m - 1, recursionLevel + 1, recursionPath);

            System.out.println(String.format("n %s m %s recursionLevel %s recursionPath %s", n, m, recursionLevel, recursionPath));
            System.out.println("method3: " + count3++);
            primeFactorsR(n / m, (n / m) - 1, recursionLevel + 1, recursionPath);
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.format("n %s m %s recursionLevel %s recursionPath %s", n, m, recursionLevel, recursionPath));
            //System.out.println("n " + n + " m - 1 " + ( m-1));
            System.out.println("method4: " + count4++);
            primeFactorsR(n, m - 1, recursionLevel + 1, recursionPath);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        primeFactors(20, 1);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
n 20 m 19 recursionLevel 1 recursionPath 1
method4: 1
n 20 m 18 recursionLevel 2 recursionPath 1-2
method4: 2
n 20 m 17 recursionLevel 3 recursionPath 1-2-3
method4: 3
n 20 m 16 recursionLevel 4 recursionPath 1-2-3-4
method4: 4
n 20 m 15 recursionLevel 5 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5
method4: 5
n 20 m 14 recursionLevel 6 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6
method4: 6
n 20 m 13 recursionLevel 7 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7
method4: 7
n 20 m 12 recursionLevel 8 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
method4: 8
n 20 m 11 recursionLevel 9 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
method4: 9
n 20 m 10 recursionLevel 10 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
method2: 1
n 10 m 9 recursionLevel 11 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11
method4: 10
n 10 m 8 recursionLevel 12 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12
method4: 11
n 10 m 7 recursionLevel 13 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13
method4: 12
n 10 m 6 recursionLevel 14 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14
method4: 13
n 10 m 5 recursionLevel 15 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15
method2: 2
n 5 recursionLevel 16 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16
method1 1
n 10 m 5 recursionLevel 15 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15
method3: 1
n 2 recursionLevel 16 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-17
method1 2
n 20 m 10 recursionLevel 10 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
method3: 2
n 2 recursionLevel 11 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-18
method1 3
```

Check this lines from result:

```
n 10 m 5 recursionLevel 15 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15
method2: 2
n 5 recursionLevel 16 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16
method1 1
n 10 m 5 recursionLevel 15 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15
method3: 1
```

Function with ID 15, called function with ID 16, which printed line:

```
n 5 recursionLevel 16 recursionPath 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16
```

After that, call returned from 16 to 15 and `n` value in function 15 is still `10`.

Comment: so in other words method3 will not execute until method2 gets a return right?... but why method3 executes first 10 and 5, when 20 and 10 was passed first in recursionPath = 10 (firstone)... by the way thanks for all the explanation

Comment: Don't try to identify function by your "method"-lines. Use `recursionPath` to identify what that's the same function. Last number in `recursionPath` shows unique ID of current function. So, if we look at logs after `Check this lines from result` - `method2: 2` and `method3: 1` lines printed by same function with ID 15. And between those prints you have call to `primeFactorsR` (it becomes call with ID 16). And this call with ID 16 prints 'method1 1' line and returns back to call 15. PS: Use "upvotes" to mark usefulness of answers and comments (read this site FAQ).